# Программа на питоне

Tags: python

Можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы кроме года, тут выводились ещё и данные взятые в кавычки? вот код:

```
a = ['Ivan Ivanov 03.2.2001',2001]
b = ['Lena Ivanovna 04.10.2015',2015]
c = ['Kolya Chernov 10.10.1998',1998]
d = ['Ilia Chernov 12.4.1989',1989]
e = ['Maksim Iliev 01.01.1992',1992]
f = ['Aleksandr Belov 13.02.2018',2018]
g = ['Sergey Petrov 08.03.1980',1980]
h = ['Katya Sorokina 05.12.1999',1999]
j = ['Vika Puzareva 09.11.2000',2000]
m = ['Ksenia Trubochkina 14.07.2002',2002]
x=3
o = [a[1],b[1],c[1],d[1],e[1],f[1],g[1],h[1],j[1],m[1]]
l = print(min(o))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да - это можно сделать:

```
o = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, j, m]
print(min(o, key=lambda x: x[1]))
```

Результат

```
['Sergey Petrov 08.03.1980', 1980]
```

В функцию `min` можно передать функцию, как выбирать данные и что с ними делать, чтобы найти минимум. Это можно делать через обычные функции, а можно через `lamda`, что в данном случае проще.

Чтобы получить только имя надо:

```
print(min(o, key=lambda x: x[1])[0])
```

Comment: А можно убрать числа, которые идут после запятой? Т.е при выводеm например ['Ivan Ivanov 03.2.2001',2001] убрать число 2001?

Comment: @Skilef Я просто ответ обновлю свой.